# Setting up a local machine to only send e-mails

Tags: raspberry-pi, email, postfix, gmail

I have installed a Raspberry device on my home network from which I want to receive periodic e-mails for a certain manner.

I wish to use the `mailutils` in order to send them via my scripts but I didn't quite manage to set up `postfix` successfully in order to do that.

Specifically, when is it possible to do this by linking one `gmail` account that I have? If so, how can this be achieved? While configuring the `postfix` i am asked to provide my hostname but...that's a localhost machine running on my home network.

Which steps should I follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `postfix`, `sendmail` or `Exim` for this purpose. Far easier to configure and less resource hungry is any lightweight, send-only MTA like:

- https://wiki.debian.org/msmtp, or
- https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP

I used `ssmtp` and it is dead simple and effective. `msmtp` is a newer replacement, a bit more flexible one.

Once you have `msmtp` installed use GMail smtp server only. If you do not know how to do it switch on pop/smtp access on GMail and have for example Thunderbird configured for GMail. You can than use the same settings in `msmtp` as described in the Debian wiki.